# Why my mesh is spotted?

Tags: mesh

When i try to extrude a part of my mesh

[image]

the "rendered" mesh (when you press shft +z) is like that

[image]

I can't understand why. I'm pretty sure this isn't the right result . . . the mesh should be homogeneous, not like that, spotted.

Comment: this normaly happens when you have two+ faces above each other and then does blender now know what he should render. What happens when you go to edit mode, select the object > press W > remove doubles?

Comment: God bless you! Blender removes 38 vertices and now it works! Is this usually the best way to avoid these situations? Remove doubles?

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. I dont make such a complex things so I dont need to remove so much doubles but it is an simple way to solve this problem